# How to Host ,Publish and use wcf rest service(Asp.Net Webapplication) in iis with vs2012..?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to host my sample WCF Rest service in local IIS. I got error like "**Web deployment task failed. (A value for the 'setAclUser' setting must be specified when the 'setAcl' provider is used with a physical path"** .Please help me to solve this error.